# How to add header on a javascript file created in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij to write javascript code. I want to add a customized file header on each newly created file. How can I set it up on Intellij?

Answer (score 2):

You can change it by going to `Settings` > `File and Code Templates` and select `Javascript File` and update the content.

[image]